# Php multi stream library

Tags: php, sockets, stream

Is there any php library (class) to deal with multiple http requests with stream_select? Or may be with non-blocking sockets.

Comment: Is there a reason for not using the curl_multi_ functions?

Answer (score 0):

I assume an [`HTTPRequestPool`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.httprequestpool.php) does what you are after?

Comment: yes, I also tried both HTTPRequestPool, and multicurl. But Php slows too much with more then 10-20 "threads". With amount of 50 threads 70-80% of them got timeout or dont resolve dns.

Comment: Hmm, as the `HTTP` package uses curl under the hood I'm not surprised that when 1 fails they both fail. However, I sincerely doubt you will find a significantly more effective method in PHP, it's pretty streamlined. Could be you are just reaching the limits of your hardware/environment resources.

Answer (score 0):

This might be overkill, but check out [NanoServ](http://nanoserv.si.kz/) - a "server daemon framework for PHP 5.1+"

Here's a very minimal sample: "Dumb HTTP Server", from the examples page:

```
<?php

require "nanoserv/handlers/HTTP/Server.php"; 

class dumb_httpd extends \Nanoserv\HTTP\Server {    
    public function on_Request($url) {    
        return "You asked for url : <b>{$url}</b>\n";
    }

}

Nanoserv::New_Listener("tcp://0.0.0.0:800", "dumb_httpd")->Activate();
Nanoserv::Run();

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Checkout the code in http://drupal.org/project/httprl. I plan on pushing this lib to github once I get it more polished; something that can be ran outside of drupal. It should do what your looking for.